# htaccess RewriteRule not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My first question here hope to find the right answer to my problem.

Here it is:

I try to transform `http://mysite.it/home.php?pagina=ciao` to `http://mysite.it/ciao`

I put inside my `.htaccess` this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home.php?(.*)$ $1
```

It shows me: `http://mysite.it/?pagina=ciao`

I know that something is wrong in the RewriteRule but I don't understand how to pick only after `home.php?pagina=` to take `ciao`,I have this on my PHP page `$get= @$_GET ['pagina'];`

I say thanks in advice and hope to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /home\.php\?pagina=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(home)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(home)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ home.php?pagina=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Really thank you! i solve this problem! i check other than 2 week. Thanks thanks thanks. I'm new in this type of things and try to learn.

Comment: can I ask you one thing? If I want to hide the .php when the URL is http://mysite.it/home.php what rule I have to add?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ /home.php?pagina=$1
```

I hope you're not doing :

```
require_once($get);
```

after that code, since that would be very dangerous...

Comment: No I'm not doing require_once($get);